# Bittrex toke my BTCP tokens

Tags: wallet, legal, fraud, bittrex

As some of you recall, we had the BTC ZCL fork this year. For those who had the ZCL on the Bittrex wallet, they were convert to BTCP, but Bittrex wasn´t trading, but it was allow to keep those tokens on the wallet.
Due to the market down, I left my tokens on bittrex wallet, hopping one day would trade BTCP.
Yesterday I find out that all my tokens were lost. Bittrex canceled all the wallets. All this was done with no warning, at least I didn’t got one. It´s amazing the amount of mail trash that we get from these exchanges and the important things are take like this. In Bittrex defense, they say that, an email was sent. We are talking about money here...keeping your money it´s not something that you inform over email, or you have to make sure that everyone got the message. Imagine if your bank does that, it would be his last day.
I think this is the kind of attitude that makes crypto a joke to general people and undervalued.
Where can I press charge, or report this in europe?
To be honest as you imagine I did not had many tokens (otherwise I would keep then on a wallet), but is still money. The worst thing here is attitude, it was very disappointing.

Comment: This is a legal question and not specific to cryptocurrencies